# what will be the fix for "no match for 'operator<<'"

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to create an undirected weighted graph and iterate over it, but I get an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > adj_list;

    int v,e;
    pair<int,int >p,q;
    cin>>v>>e;
    adj_list.resize(e);
    int a,b,w;
    for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
        cin>>a>>b>>w;
        p=make_pair(a,w);
        q=make_pair(b,w);
        adj_list[a].push_back(p);
        adj_list[b].push_back(q);
    }
    vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator j;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
        j=adj_list[i].begin();
         cout<<i<<" is connected to : ";
        while(j!=adj_list[i].end()){
            cout<< *j.first <<" "<< *j.second;
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what will be the fix of this code ?
the compiler is showing this error

```
[path]\s2.cpp|23|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >'})|
```

Comment: this is the code which is giving error                                                          
    vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator j;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
        j=adj_list[i].begin();
         cout<<i<<" is connected to : ";
        while(j!=adj_list[i].end()){
            cout<< *j.first <<" "<< *j.second;
            ++j;
        }
    }

Comment: `*j.first` is equivalent to `*(j.first)`. You meant `(*j).first`, which we usually write `j->first`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the comment, you should use `j->first` instead of `*j.first` because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), member access operator has a higher precedence than deference operator. So `*j.first` is equivalent to `*(j.first)`.

In addition, the size of `adj_list` should be `v` instead of `e` assuming `v` means vertex and is labelled in the range of `[0..v-1]`. So the correct code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<vector<pair<int,int> > > adj_list;
    int v,e;
    pair<int,int >p,q;
    cin>>v>>e;
    adj_list.resize(v);
    int a,b,w;
    for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
        cin>>a>>b>>w;
        p=make_pair(a,w);
        q=make_pair(b,w);
        adj_list[a].push_back(p);
        adj_list[b].push_back(q);
    }
    vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator j;
    for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
        j=adj_list[i].begin();
        cout<<i<<" is connected to : ";
        while(j!=adj_list[i].end()){
            cout<< j->first <<" "<< j->second;
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @RishabhVerma if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.